# Change the dummy data jquery in inverted commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know how to replace this dummy code for Jquery in the **inverted commas**

this is fine but if I replace the jquery dummy data to the razor code i got error...

```
jQuery('<div class="table"><input class="data-cell data-category" /><input class="data-cell data-value" type="number" step="10" /><input class="data-button delete-button" type="button" value="X" /><input class="data-button addnew-button" type="button" value="V" /></div>').prependTo('#data-table');
```

to the following razor code

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Role</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.checkBox1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.checkBox1)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.checkBox1)
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

when i try to do that The @ sigh of the razor code cause to error,how to overcome it and replace the code inside the  inverted commas to the razor code?

Comment: can't find any part in your razor code that related to the javascript. which line actually caused the error?

Comment: @PasitR.-if you take the code that I put in razor and replace the inverted commas of the Jquery with it you will see the error since its not ignore the @ sigh...any idea how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

not sure is it compilation error or just warning in your code editor

this is how I combine javascript with value from Razor output

```
var html = '@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Value)';
$(html).prependTo('#somewhere');
```

if your want to render whole HTML output from the Razor's View. You can do this

```
var html = '@Html.Partial("ViewName", Model)';
$(html).prependTo('#somewhere');
```

BTW this seem bad smells in design.

alternately, use ajax $.get to your Action url that return PartialView would be simpler

```
$.get('@Url.Action("ActionName")', function(html){
    $(html).prependTo('#somewhere');
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the support! Can I share the project in one drive...when I put for example the code you provided in first I got error in the code editor